# Need to call the function after submit the form using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Need to call the the function after submit the form. In my controller contains two api calls.I need to call the first API and get the "sld" value from that and pass the "sld" value to second API Url after that execute the Second API. But i got a two api output at the same time. please suggest any solution to call the first api after that display the second API data.

My Controller Code

```
    public function domaincheck(Request $request)
       {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    //set_time_limit(300);
        $sld = $request['sld'];
        $tld = $request['tld'];
        $response = file_get_contents('https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld='. $sld .'&tld='. $tld .'&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw&responsetype=xml');  
        $data = simplexml_load_string($response);
        $configdata   = json_encode($data);
        $final_data = json_decode($configdata,true);// Use true to get data in array rather than object
        // dd($final_data);



        $response1 = file_get_contents('http://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=GETNAMESUGGESTIONS&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw&SearchTerm='. $sld .'&MaxResults=50&ResponseType=XML');       
        $data1 = simplexml_load_string($response1);
        $configdata1   = json_encode($data1);
        $final_data1 = json_decode($configdata1,true);// Use true to get data in array rather than object
        //dd($final_data1);

        }
```

My View Code

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="get"> 


  <div class="form-group">
     <div class=" col-lg-2"></div>
     <div class="col-lg-8">
         <div class="input-group m-b">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding-left:10px; background-color: #999;" class='unclickable'>www</span>
            <input type="text" name="sld" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">

  <select class="form-control" name="tld" style="width: 100px;">

  <?php $j = 0; ?>
  @foreach($final_data2['tldlist']['tld'] as $value)
  <?php $j++; ?> 
  @endforeach

  @for ($i = 0; $i < $j-1;)
  <option value="{{($final_data2['tldlist']['tld'][$i]['tld'])}}">{{($final_data2['tldlist']['tld'][$i]['tld'])}}</option>

  <?php $i++; ?> 
  @endfor


      </select>  
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" >Submit</button>  
      </span>
      </div>
      <p class="text-center text-dark customFont" >
                    @foreach($final_data as $key=>$value)
                      @if($key=='DomainName')
                        <b>{{$value}}</b> <b>-</b>
                      @endif 
                      @if($key=='RRPText')
                          <b>{{$value}}</b>
                      @endif
                    @endforeach
                </p>



  @foreach($final_data1['DomainSuggestions']['Domain'] as $value)

  {{$value}}<br>

  @endforeach
```

Please suggest any solution to solve this issue

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you want to achieve? Return the results of both API calls or something else?

Comment: Yes i need to return the results of both api calls but when i pass the "sld and tld" value in first api it shows the domain is available or not available at the same time i need to pass the "sld" value in the second api. when i was submitted the form it will return the results both api calls.

now i had a problem for i couldn't submit the form but it will return the second api output.i don't want to return the results without form submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather have store those two API calls as functions into separate folder under *app* directory. For example, under *\app\Repositories* directory you can create two separate php files and store the api calls as function. While doing this, please take class based approach. See following example, inside *DomainSuggestion.php*

```
    <?php

        namespace App\Repositories;


        class DomainSuggestion
        {
            function getdomain(&$domainArray)
            {
               $response = file_get_contents('https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld='. $domainArray[0] .'&tld='. $domainArray[1] .'&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw&responsetype=xml');
    $data = simplexml_load_string($response);
            $configdata   = json_encode($data);
            $final_data = json_decode($configdata,true);
return $final_data;
}
}
```

and in your controller funtion

```
use App\Repositories\DomainSuggestion;

     $sld = $request['sld'];
        $tld = $request['tld'];
        $domainArray = array($sld, $tld);

        $dataObject = new DomainSuggestion();
        $result = $dataObject->getdomain($domainArray);
```

Initialize the object of this class and call the function (inside your controller). The returned value from the first function can be utilized into the second call. You can also pass required parameter into the function. Don't forget to include the function directory into your controller (use App\Repositories\ClassName;)

Comment: I have created two files in app/repositories directory but i have a doubt how to call the class name in my controller

Comment: Please apply this approach into your controller function.                           
$objectName = new ClassName();                                              $result = $objectName->function();                                                           Here, the $result variable will store the return type value from the _function()_ .

Comment: If you have parameterized function, then you can pass like this:           $result = $objectName->function($a, $b);                                                       
 where $a and $b are parameters to be passed.

Comment: This is my code
`
namespace App\Repositories;
class DomainSuggestion{
    public function getdomain(){
        $sld=$_REQUEST[$sld];
        $tld=$_REQUEST[$tld];
        $response=file_get_contents('http://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=GETNAMESUGGESTIONS&uid=decksys&pw=Amy.th3ist4917&SearchTerm='. $sld .'&MaxResults=50&ResponseType=XML');
        $data=simplexml_load_string($response);
        $final_data=json_encode($data);
        $response_data=json_decode($final_data,true);
        return view('clientlayout.main.registerdomain',compact('final_data'));
    }
}
`

Comment: don't mistake me . I didn't understant how to call the Class name into my controller.Please explain

Comment: don't return view from your function but  **return $final_data** from your function and it will work

Comment: will you please give me some example code for this.Because I don't use this type of function before.can you please develop this function to the above code.Because am a very new to laravel framework

Comment: Thank you so much. First api is perfectly working. I want to pass the $sld value to second API url. How to pass the $sld value to second API url. within same Controller

Comment: Second API Code - 
class Suggest
        {
            function getSuggestdomain($domainArray)
            {
            $response1 = file_get_contents('http://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=GETNAMESUGGESTIONS&uid=decksys&pw=Amy.th3ist4917&SearchTerm='. $domainArray[0] .'&MaxResults=50&ResponseType=XML');
            $data1 = simplexml_load_string($response1);
            $configdata1   = json_encode($data1);
            $suggest_domain = json_decode($configdata1,true);
            return $suggest_domain;
}

please suggest solution how to call this to my controller.

Comment: I included the function directory as follows 

use App\Repositories\DomainSuggestion;
use App\Repositories\DomainChecker;

use in the same controller please suggest any solutions

Comment: you are great the second api is also working but when I submit the empty form i got an error search term  missing ($sld).I need the solution for this part only.

Comment: _<input type="text" name="sld" class="form-control" required>_  Adding  required at the last to any input checks if the user is submitting without any value or not but if you want more validation then go through this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)

Comment: you are great the second api is also working but when I submit the empty form i got an error search term  missing ($sld).I need the solution for this part only. I return the two api data in same controller and the same function. When i run this url [http://localhost:8000/test]  i got an error search term  missing if i fill the form and run url know i got an exact output please suggest any solution [http://localhost:8000/test?sld=decksys&tld=com]

Comment: If you only want to take values from url [localhost:8000/test?sld=decksys&tld=com] then apply this method into your controller: _use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;_  $sld=Input::get('sld'); $tld=Input::get('tld');